# How to set hop count to 1?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, one-hop

I have set up an onion service to access my local network without forwarding ports. The service doesn't need to be anonymous and I am the only one accessing it (client authentication). So I want to have as few hops as possible to access it.

How can I configure the hop count to absolute minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `HiddenServiceSingleHopMode 1` and `HiddenServiceNonAnonymousMode 1` in your server's torrc configuration file. This will use a single hop circuit on the onion service's side. You cannot change the number of hops on the client's side (without using Tor's control API), so between the client and the onion service there will be 4 hops in total.

Comment: I got the following warning. Setting the Socksport to 0 resolved it.
`[warn] Failed to parse/validate config: HiddenServiceNonAnonymousMode is incompatible with using Tor as an anonymous client. Please set Socks/Trans/NATD/DNSPort to 0, or revert HiddenServiceNonAnonymousMode to 0.`